# setuid bit on shared object

Tags: c, shared-objects, setuid

I know that to have a .so loaded, the e'x'ecute bit must be set. However, I wonder what is the effect of  +s (setuid) bit on the .so ?
 If the main program is not "setuid" set, but the .so it loads is setuid, does it change the uid ? I found not but would be happy to get some explanation.

```
$ cat a.c 
# include <stdio.h>


extern void func();


void main()
{

    func();
}
$ cat b.c 
# include <stdio.h>
# include <unistd.h>


void func()
{
    printf("UID %d",geteuid());
}


gcc --shared -o libb.so ./b.c
sudo chown root: libb.so ; sudo chmod +s ./libb.so
gcc a.c  -L. -Wl,-R. -lb
```

that does not make any different (as-if the setuid in the .so is ignored).

Comment: It does not have any effect.

Comment: It has no effect.  Once the process is running, loading a shared library does not change its UID or GID characteristics — and neither should it.